# Question about analytic polyhedra

Tags: several-complex-variables

Let $\Pi\subset\subset U\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ be an analytic polyhedron $$\Pi=\{z\in  U:|f_j(z)|<1,1\le j\le m\}$$ where $f_1,\ldots,f_m\in H(U)$, the following equality holds?

$$\overline{\Pi}=\{z\in  U:|f_j(z)|\le1,1\le j\le m\}$$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Look in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_polyhedron).

Answer (score 1):

It's clear (by continuity of the $f_j$) that 
$$\overline{\Pi} \subset \{z\in  U:|f_j(z)|\le1,1\le j\le m\}.$$

Conversely, if $|f_j(w)| = 1$, then every neighborhood of $w$ contains a point where $|f_j| < 1$ (otherwise $|f_j| \ge 1$ on $\partial B$ for every small ball centered at $w$, but then $f_j$ is zero-free on $B$, since zero sets can't be compact, so $1/f_j$ is holomorphic on $B$ which would violate the maximum modulus principle). So $\partial \Pi$ contains the union of the hypersurfaces where $|f_j| = 1$, i.e.
$$\overline{\Pi} \supset \{z\in  U:|f_j(z)|\le1,1\le j\le m\}.$$

Comment: Notice that if $\Pi=\{(z,w)\in  \mathbb{C}^2:|z^2-2|<1,|z-1|<2,|w|<1\}$ 

$\{(z,w)\in  \mathbb{C}^2:|z^2-2|\le1,|z-1|\le2,|w|\le1\}\not\subset \overline{\Pi}$, consider $(z,w)=(-1,0)$, but if the domain $U$ is reduced, the equality holds.

Comment: You are right, I unconsciously assumed that.